# Determine upper and lower bounds given an integer

Tags: python

I have a small task within my script that I need to handle and i'm really not sure how I should go about doing it.

The function takes an integer and I need to find upper and lower bounds that the integer lies between.

The upper and lower bounds will always be 5 numbers apart. For example, if the inputted integer is `4` then the lower bound would be `0` and the upper bound would be `5`.

Another example would be if the inputted integer is 26, the lower bound would be `25` and the upper bound would be `30`.

Could anyone give me some starting information as to what would be a good way to go about tackling this? I'm thinking that I could just find the lower bound and then add 5 to it in order to find the upper bound? I'm just not entirely certain what would be the most efficient way to find one bound.

Comment: Why `0` and `5` and not `1` and `6` or `2` and `7` or ...

Comment: The question seems pretty specific and clear to me. I'd be interested to know why someone voted to close for being off-topic; this question isn't requesting debugging help, it's an algoritm question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's essentially a grid of squares. The lowest point on the grid is 0,0. Each box has a length of 5 and a width of 5. If a point lies on a line it won't matter because I have other inputted integers to tell me exactly where on the grid it lies.

Comment: What should happen if the input is a multiple of 5? For instance, if you have `25`, do you want `[20, 25]` or `[25, 30]`?

Comment: @VincentSavard I have other inputted integers that will determine which square on the grid that will tell me exactly which bounds to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
number = input()
lowerBound = number - (number % 5)
upperBound = lowerBound + 5
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you very much. I really didn't expect it to be this simple and straightforward. Thank you very much.